# Colocar uma função dentro da ENV no Dockerfile

Tags: docker

Estou precisando criar uma Variável que captura o Gateway da interface de rede do Docker, segue o comando:

```
RUN declare -x SERVER_IP=$(ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }')
ENV GATEWAY="$SERVER_IP"
...
```

Durante a construção do Dockerfile parece que não funciona deixando em branco, tentei também dessa forma direto:

```
ENV GATEWAY="$(ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }')"
```

Também nada, deixando os detalhes estou usando a Imagem Ubuntu:16.04 e antes chegar na variável já instalo o `iproute2` para o comando `ip`.

Comment: quando você setar o valor de `GATEWAY` usando o comando `ENV` do `Dockerfile` o valor dele vai se manter na imagem, mas não vai ser renovado quando você iniciar um contêiner... é isso mesmo que você quer? não seria melhor pegar essa informação no entrypoint da usa imagem?

Comment: Existe um software que vai iniciar através do `supervisord`, e ele procura essa variável no sistema mas como o docker não inicia o `init` eu pecorrir seta uma variável dinâmica, no caso do ENTRYPOINT não sei utilizar pode me dá um exemplo?

Comment: ficou um pouco grande... então escrevi uma resposta mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando `ENV` tem a ideia de definir variáveis "estáticas", por exemplo:

`ENV ENV_TYPE DEV
ENV PROD_VERSION 3.1.1`

Ele não vai tentar processar o valor da variável, irá apenas aceitá-la como valor final.

Para os valores que são calculados/recuperados no momento da execução seria melhor usar `ENTRYPOINT` ou o comando `CMD` para adicionar um script a execução do contêiner, dessa forma toda vez que executar `docker run suaimage` esse script será executado.

Exemplo:

Em uma pasta tenho dois arquivos: `entrypoint.sh` e `Dockerfile`:

- `entrypoint.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

export SERVER_IP=$(ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }')
echo "SERVER_IP: $SERVER_IP"
```

- `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM alpine:3.5

ADD entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Dessa forma quando você fizer o `docker build` e `docker run` a saída será como abaixo:

```
$ docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 28.67 kB
Step 1/3 : FROM alpine:3.5
 ---> 4a415e366388
Step 2/3 : ADD entrypoint.sh /
 ---> bb398e3cd80a
Removing intermediate container 7d1f1aa2ba81
Step 3/3 : ENTRYPOINT /bin/sh /entrypoint.sh
 ---> Running in 1c71f190fa2e
 ---> f43f141922cf
Removing intermediate container 1c71f190fa2e
Successfully built f43f141922cf
$ docker run test
SERVER_IP: 172.17.0.1
```

No lugar de `echo "SERVER_IP: $SERVER_IP"` deve estar a lógica específica para iniciar o serviço que o seu contêiner pretende prestar.

Documentação sobre entrypoints: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint